# Find duplicates in first column and take average based on third column

Tags: java, arrays, string, java-8, dynamic-arrays

My issue here is I need to compute average time for each Id and compute average time of each id.

Sample data

`T1,2020-01-16,11:16pm,start
 T2,2020-01-16,11:18pm,start
 T1,2020-01-16,11:20pm,end
 T2,2020-01-16,11:23pm,end`

I have written a code in such a way that I kept first column and third column in a map.. something like

`T1, 11:16pm`

but I could not able to compute values after keeping those values in a map.  Also tried to keep them in string array and split into line by line. By same issue facing for that approach also.
**
public class AverageTimeGenerate {

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    File file = new File("/abc.txt"); 
    try (BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file))) {
        while (true) {
            String line = reader.readLine();
            if (line == null) {
               break;
            }

          ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
          String[] tokens = line.split(",");
          for (String s: tokens) {
              list.add(s);
          }     

          Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
          String[] data = line.split(",");
          String ids= data[0];
          String dates = data[1];
          String transactionTime = data[2];
          String transactionStartAndEndTime = data[3];

          String[] transactionIds = ids.split("/n");
          String[] timeOfEachTransaction = transactionTime.split("/n");
          for(String id : transactionIds) {
              for(String time : timeOfEachTransaction) {
                  map.put(id, time);
              }
          }
      }    
   }
}
```

}

```
Can anyone suggest me is it possible to find duplicates in a map and compute values in map, Or is there any other way I can do this so that the output should be like 

`T1 2:00
 T2 5:00'
```

Comment: Your expected result of  avg is not clear.please explain how T1 2.00 and T2 5.00 is coming according to your sample data.

Comment: No I just gave numbers to understand. This data will not get those values. It will come T1 and avg time of T1 I mean end time - start time/ total no. of transactions

Comment: you can store it to Map<String, Map<String, List<Date>>> then the object would look like this { 'T1'.: {'start' : [11:00, 12:00 ...], 'end' : [11:30, 12:30...] }, 'T2' .. }. It would be easier to calculate the avg I think since you need to differentiate the 'start' and the 'end' time

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what is your logic to complete the average time but you can save data in map for one particular transaction. The map structure can be like this. Transaction id will be the key and all the time will be in array list.

```
Map<String,List<String>> map = new HashMap<String,List<String>>();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this:

```
 Map<String, String> result = Files.lines(Paths.get("abc.txt"))
            .map(line -> line.split(","))
            .map(arr -> {
                try {
                    return new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<>(arr[0],
                                          new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm").parse(arr[2]));
                } catch (ParseException e) {
                    return null;
                }
            }).collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Map.Entry::getKey,
                    Collectors.collectingAndThen(Collectors
                                    .mapping(Map.Entry::getValue, Collectors.toList()),
                            list -> toStringTime.apply(convert.apply(list)))));
```

for simplify I've declared two functions.

```
Function<List<Date>, Long> convert = list -> (list.get(1).getTime() - list.get(0).getTime()) / 2;
Function<Long, String> toStringTime = l -> l / 60000 + ":" + l % 60000 / 1000;
```